# MongoDB: how to get the count of a particular document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I have a schema of USERS:

```
const signUpTemplate = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullname: {
    type: String,
  },
  purchasedCourses: {
    type: Array,
    default: [] //Here courseIdList is pushed with unique ID and course name
  }
});
```

And a schema of courses:

```
const courseIdList = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String },
  courseName: { type: String },
  purchaseDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

How can I get the total count of users having a same course? Like if a course name 'A' is purchased by 10 different users how can get this total number?

Comment: why does course schema have a purchase date? doesn't make sense as it can vary from user to user. do you mean createdAt?

Comment: This was just a part of my schema. currently I am taking the purchase date from the backend API and pushing it to a new field on DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$lookup`, you can look for the matching records of `courses` collection into the `users` collection.

```
db.courses.aggregate(
   [{ $lookup: { 
      from: "users", 
      localField: "_id", 
      foreignField: "purchasedCourses._id", 
      as: "coursesCount" 
   }}, 
   { $addFields: { "coursesCount": { $size: "$coursesCount" } } }]
)
```

[Working example](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/8T0Y9HEcq7W)

[Read More](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) on `$lookup`;